# Select Statement for localhost and insert into network database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

module for localhost connection

## This is my module for connecting localhost

```
    Function connect()
    con.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};server=localhost;database=tablelocal;uid=root;pwd=root;option=0"     
    con.Open()
    End Function

    Function Disconnect()
    con.Close()
    End Function
```

module for network connection

## This is my module for connecting through network

```
    Function connectnetwork()
    con.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};server=192.168.0.1;database=samplenetwork;uid=root;pwd=root;option=0"     
    con.Open()
    End Function

    Function Disconnectnetwork()
    con.Close()
    End Function
```

## Please See my edit

```
    Dim sourceConnection As New OdbcConnection(connect())
    Dim destinationConnection As New OdbcConnection(connectNetwork())
    Dim adapter As New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * from local ", sourceConnection)
    Dim insertCommand As New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO network", destinationConnection)

    With insertCommand.Parameters
        OdbcCommand = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Insert into network select * from local ", con)
        OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()   
    End With

    adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand

    'Keep the RowState of each row as Added so it is ready to be inserted.'
     adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False

    Dim table As New DataTable

    'Retrieve data from source database.'
     adapter.Fill(table)

    'Save data to destination database.'
     adapter.Update(table)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: there is no error but if i will excecute the data will transfer local only but it will not go to network server

Comment: Can somebody help me for simple code from local to network,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two different connections with your data adapter, e.g.

```
Dim sourceConnection As New OdbcConnection("source connection string here")
Dim destinationConnection As New OdbcConnection("destination connection string here")
Dim adapter As New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT ...", sourceConnection)
Dim insertCommand As New OdbcCommand("INSERT ...", destinationConnection)

With insertCommand.Parameters
    'Add parameters here.'
End With

adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand

'Keep the RowState of each row as Added so it is ready to be inserted.'
adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False

Dim table As New DataTable

'Retrieve data from source database.'
adapter.Fill(table)

'Save data to destination database.'
adapter.Update(table)
```

Comment: Please see my edited code if I am correct, could you give me example for add parameters? sorry but i am new user for VB

Comment: If you're using ADO.NET then you really should already know how to add parameters.  There are examples all over the place and they are not hard to find.  Here's one I prepared earlier: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: yeah I know but i tried to run my program it still wrong, can you see my edited code as your code basis, because im confused if my calling of connection string is correct, and could you fill the parameters?

Comment: Telling us that something "doesn't work" or "is wrong" is all but useless.  We need to know EXACTLY what happens, which includes the error message if there's an exception.

Comment: No I won't fill the parameters for you.  I couldn't even if I wanted to because I don't know the schema of the table you're inserting to but I wouldn't anyway.  I've shown you how to do it.  Now do it.  If you try and it fails then you can ask for help on that specifically.

Comment: Ok then, take a look again my edit code, Error is in part of connectionstring at connectNetwork. Invalid Operation Exception

Comment: Version 3.51 of the MySQL ODBC driver is rather old.  Is that really what you have installed?

Comment: yup!, I create another module callLocal() for sourceConnection, which contains the connect() and disconnect() and the other one is callnetwork() for destinationConnection, contais connectnetwork() and disconnectnetwork().

Comment: Well, IDK.  If you use a valid connection string then it will work.  I'm no expert in MySQL ODBC connection strings though.

Answer (score 0):

while on network all the commands and queries are Case Sensitive (for mysql)
all the things in "" (Double Quotes) must be Case Sensitive (for mysql)

Maybe try to add "Protocol=socket;" to the connection string.

OR check the firewall

sometimes firewall who didn't let it through

check [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2304/ADO-Connection-Strings#MySQL)